# Can one WCF Service return another?

Tags: c#, wcf

For example, could a WCF Service act as a factory for other WCF Services ?
E.g.:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "Foo")]
interface IThing
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoSomething();
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "Foo")]
interface IMakeThings
{
    [OperationContract]
    IThing Create(string initializationData);
}
```

Similarly can an interface take another interface as a parameter ?

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "Foo")]
interface IUseThings
{
    [OperationContract]
    void UseThing(IThing target);
}
```

Would this require adjusting known types ?

All the interfaces would be defined up front and known to both the client and the service.

Comment: There are proxies on client side, not real service instances. So the question doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: No. WCF is a **message-based** system - it passes XML serialized **data** (and data only - no code or methods) from client to server and back. It is **NOT* designed to be something like remoting or support "remote object invocation" or anything like that.

Comment: I may be missing something, but in theory it would be possible for the client side to wrap the return result of IMakeThings.Create() in an appropriate "IThing" proxy, based on the bindings to the "IMakeThings" service. The answer to this question may well be "no" which is fine, but I think the question itself makes sense.

Comment: IIRC this was possible with .Net remoting

Comment: @marc_s The fact that data gets serialized as XML with a message structure doesn't seem to me to affect the fact that the outcome is calling methods on remote objects. This to me looks like an issue of setting up further proxies and bindings.

Comment: Does the client know about the contract that the "forwarded" service implements?

Comment: @Richard Blewett Yes, the client knows about the contract the "forwarded" service implements. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. No.  When you're going over the web you're not dealing with references like you might in C# so you won't be able to return an object that is not serializable.  Even then, only the **data** that is marked as *DataMember* will come across.
2. Yes.  You would have to adjust known types, but again, that would be an interface to a *DataContract* not an *OperationContract*

Comment: I'm not looking to serialize interfaces or references, but to set up further proxies and bindings, similar to going down the ChannelFactory.CreateChannel() route that would have been used to establish the original client to service connection.

Comment: I get that, but that's how WCF works.  If you're looking to return a service of some sort it would have to be a custom object with information about the service (with instructions how to call it) as opposed to the service itself. Internally, in non-WCF code, this works because you're passing references back and forth.  Over WCF it doesn't because you're passing around static instances of data.  It MAY be possible over named pipes since that passes around memory pointers, but I'm skeptical that it would work.

Comment: Now, let me also add, that if you want to, you can set up a way for you to send the instructions back to the client on what other method options they have, most likely as a string descriptions of the service urls, and maybe the method signature, depending on how you want to skin that cat.  Your end goal is possible, just not how you're trying to go about it in your question.

Comment: That's very helpful (so this'll probably end up being the accepted answer). So if I understand you, you're suggesting the route to go would be for the service to spin up another service and return the endpoint (plus potentially some other info) as a string, so that the client can then go ahead and connect with a ChannelFactory to that endpoint ? If so, I guess my original question was about whether WCF and/or the .NET library have some functionality to reduce the burden on the programmer. This all seems possible, just awkward, which usually means the approach is wrong...

Comment: WCF is intended to be agnostic to the system, which is why you can only pass data.  To that end we can pass data to PHP, Java, JavaScript and what not.  So yes, what you're trying to do is cumbersome because it's not an intended feature of WCF and is not normally the correct approach.  I suppose you can also return a WSDL if you're doing SOAP, so that the client can construct the service client over.  That's pretty much what you're going to be doing anyway.  If your server and client are on the same box try named pipes, it may very well work.

Comment: I'm not thinking having the service "spin up" another service, instead I was thinking having a service that uses reflection to read the footprint of the other service, and then return all that as string descriptions.  Again, what you really want is a WSDL because that's exactly what the WSDL is, a text description of a service.  If I may ask, why do you need to send this type of data across?  It sounds to me like you have a bigger issue with overall architecture than how to work through this specific WCF problem.

Comment: This should probably be the start of another question but: At the moment we have an IDL defining interfaces to some back end system using dbus. The resulting bindings are a bunch of C# interfaces and proxies which handle marshalling. We also require WCF interfaces (for now identical) which will pass through to the dbus bindings. Config to setup the binding (in the WCF service) is irrelevant to the interfaces in the IDL. However, there are cases where the WCF client needs to provide that config. In the future we might keep the IDL interfaces ("IThing"), but change the mechanism ("IMakeThings").

Comment: How did you end up resolving this?

Comment: I haven't. I still want to separate my contracts from backend transport implementation details. Currently considering endpoints matched via [AddressFilterMode.Prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.addressfiltermode.aspx) where the transport details are embedded in the endpoint suffix, and there's just one actual WCF service. I still need to look into that with regards to returning the appropriate contract. Otherwise I'll just have to pollute my contracts with transport info, probably in every method call to reduce state.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. When you call a method on a WCF service that takes or returns an object, what really happens is that the object is being serialized and the serialized form is being passed back and forth.

That's why on the client side you don't get the "full blown" implementation of the `DataContract`-attributed class, but a stub that only contains the properties marked for serialization. You don't even get the methods. A WCF service is attributed as `ServiceContract`, not as `DataContract`, so this won't work at all.

The ability to use pass an interface to a service method would require the service to know which implementation is to be deserialized. While I haven't actually tried, I supposed that this won't work, but you may be able to surprise me here :-)

Comment: I believe you're correct, but for a counter-example there are callback contracts for services to call back into clients, which admittedly require explicit plumbing code, but are an example of passing a service via an interface to another service. I'm not so much after data serialization as setting up further proxies based on an existing binding.

Comment: I don't think that callback contracts work that way. I'd guess they're not passing an instance of the callback service, but the client also sets up a WCF service transparently.

Comment: You can easily set up further services for an existing binding. You can simply declare a second service in the configuration, make it use the same binding, but append to the URI. For example, your first service's URI is `net.tcp://localhost:8080/MyService/Service1`, you can simply have a secon service on URI `net.tcp://localhost:8080/MyService/Service2` (same port, same base URI!).